# Issue with web scraping Job search sites

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm web scraping the Monster job site with the search aimed at "Software Developer" and my aim is to simply print out only the jobs that have "python" listed in their description in the Python terminal, while discarding all the other jobs for Java, HTML, CSS etc. However when I run this code I end up printing all the jobs on the page.
To solve this I created a variable (called 'search') that searches for all jobs with 'python' and converts it to lowercase. Also I created a variable (called 'python_jobs') that includes all the job listings on the page.

Then I made a "for" loop that looks for every instance where 'search' is found in 'python_jobs'. However this gives the same result as before and prints out every job listing on the page anyways. Any suggestions?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer"
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="ResultsContainer")

search = results.find_all("h2", string=lambda text: "python" in text.lower())
python_jobs = results.find_all("section", class_="card-content")

print(len(search))

for search in python_jobs:
    title = search.find("h2", class_="title")
    company = search.find("div", class_="company")
    if None in (title, company):
        continue
    print(title.text.strip())
    print(company.text.strip())
    print()
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"` - maybe `title, company` is not `None` so it will not skip it

Comment: you assing elements with `python` to variable `search` but you never use it - you use only `python_jobs` and you assing it to the same variable `search` so it removes previous content from `search`. maybe you should use `for item in search` instead of `for search in python_jobs`. OR maybe you should work in different way - first in `results` find all elements which have `h2 with `python` and later use these elements (instead `reasults`) to find `sections and other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have two separated list `search` and `python_jobs` which are not related. And later you don't even use list `search`. You should rather get every item from `python_jobs` and search `python` inside this item.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer"
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="ResultsContainer")

all_jobs = results.find_all("section", class_="card-content")

for job in all_jobs:
    python = job.find("h2", string=lambda text: "python" in text.lower())
    if python:
        title = job.find("h2", class_="title")
        company = job.find("div", class_="company")
        print(title.text.strip())
        print(company.text.strip())
        print()
```

or

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer"
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="ResultsContainer")

all_jobs = results.find_all("section", class_="card-content")

for job in all_jobs:
    title = job.find("h2")
    if title:
        title = title.text.strip()
        if 'python' in title.lower():
            company = job.find("div", class_="company").text.strip()
            print(title)
            print(company)
            print()
```